# could you explain a sentence about reporting?

Tags: meaning, translation

"Half-yearly reporting included in overall project management costs"
a report about the costs of the overall management of the project? or something else?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this sentence means that the cost of reporting half-yearly is included in overall project management costs.

So no report, but the costs for reporting come under overall project management costs.